# How to convert an array of ASCII values to an integer in C

Tags: c, arrays, hex

I have an array which has ASCII characters.
suppose, `Array[4]`.
In that, `Array[0]=0x38, Array[1]=0x30, Array[2]=0x30, Array[4]=0x30` ==> Basically it stored value 8000 in different bytes.

Now I want to extract 8000 out of this Array to uint32 Some_Count variable. Can someone suggest me how to extract it?
Finally Some_Count should have 8000 in it.

Please suggest.

Comment: Did you mean `Array[4]=0x30` to be `Array[3]=0x30`? There are only 4 elements here. If you have `char Array[] = "8000";` you can apply `int Some_Count = atoi(Array)` or other functions. Or if you manually place each character you need an extra element where you write a `'\0'` string terminator.

Comment: You can use `atoi`.

Comment: What have you tried? What part are you having problems implementing?

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>
unsigned int main()
{
    char Array[4] = {0x38, 0x30, 0x30, 0x30};
    unsigned int result = 0, i = 0;
    for( i = 0; i< 4; i++)
    { 
        result = result*10 + (Array[i] - '0`');
    }
    printf("Result = %d\n", result);
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h> 

int main()
{
    char buffer[3] = {'1', '2', '3'};
    int num = atoi(buffer);
    printf("number: %d ", num);
    return 0;
}
```

output:

```
number: 123
```